# Tensorflow, Keras: How to set add_loss in Keras layer with stop gradient?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

### Question 1

We know that we can use `tf.stop_gradient(B)` to prevent variable `B` being trained in backpropagation. But I have no idea how to stop `B` in certain loss.

To put is simple, assume our loss is:

```
loss = categorical_crossentropy + my_loss
B = tf.stop_gradient(B)
```

where **both `categorical_crossentropy` and `my_loss` all depends on `B`**. So, if we set stop gradient for `B`, both of them will take `B` as constant.

But how do I set only `my_loss` stop gradient w.r.t `B`, leave `categorical_crossentropy` unchanged? Something like `B = tf.stop_gradient(B, myloss)`

My code for that would be:

```
my_loss = ...
B = tf.stop_gradient(B)
categorical_crossentropy = ...
loss = categorical_crossentropy + my_loss
```

Will that work? Or, how to make that work?

---

### Question 2

Okay, guys, if Q1 can be solved, my final quest is how to do that in custom layer?

To put it specific, assume we have a custom layer, which have trainable weights `A` and `B` and self loss `my_loss` for this layer only.

```py
class My_Layer(keras.layers.Layer):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(My_Layer, self).__init__(**kwargs)
    def build(self, input_shape):
        self.w = self.add_weight(name='w', trainable=True)
        self.B = self.add_weight(name='B', trainable=True)
        my_loss = w * B
        # tf.stop_gradient(w)
        self.add_loss(my_loss)
```

How do I make `w` only trainable for model loss (MSE, crossentropy etc.),  and `B` only trainable for `my_loss`?

If I add that `tf.stop_gradient(w)`, will that stop `w` for `my_loss` only or the final loss of the model?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Question 1**

When you run `y = tf.stop_gradient(x)`, you create a `StopGradient` operation whose input is `x` and output is `y`. This operation behaves like an identity, i.e. the value of `x` is the same as the value of `y` except that gradients don't flow from `y` to `x`.

If you want to have gradients flow to `B` only from some losses, you can simply do:

```
B_no_grad = tf.stop_gradient(B)
loss1 = get_loss(B)  # B will be updated because of loss1
loss2 = get_loss(B_no_grad)   # B will not be updated because of loss2
```

Things should become clear when you think about the computation graph you are building. `stop_gradient` allows you to create an "identity" node for any tensor (not just variable) that does not allow gradients to flow through it.

**Question 2**

I don't know how to do this while using a model loss that you specify using a string (e.g. `model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', ...)` because you don't control its construction. However, you can do it by adding losses using `add_loss` or building a model-level loss yourself using model outputs. For the former, just create some losses using plain variables and some using `*_no_grad` versions, add them all using `add_loss()`, and compile your model with `loss=None`.

Comment: Just shooting from the hip here, but https://keras.io/losses/ says you can pass a function to `compile` and not just a string, like  `model.compile(loss=losses.mean_squared_error, optimizer='sgd')` as opposed to `model.compile(loss='mean_squared_error', optimizer='sgd')`

Comment: What if I want gradients from loss1 to affect the weights of say layer 1-2 only (not layer 3-4) and gradients from loss 2 to affect layer 3-4 only (not layer 1-2). This is exactly what you want for example when you're trying to add two different custom regularization terms to a variational autoencoder, one for the encoder only and another one for the decoder only, while they have to be trained jointly.

Comment: @Kristof Have you ever figured this out? How can you have loss1 affect only layers 1-2 and loss2 affect only layers 3-4?